# Is there any way in Netezza Stored Procedure to put output into file

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

Is there any way in Netezza Stored Procedure to put output into a file?  By output I mean statements from Notice statement in Netezza.  Also we can't use any shell or other script because the SP is being invoked via a tool which cannot execute shell scripts but only make DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to write these values to a file -

```
1) Write UDX which can put your statements to disk
2) Every raise notice statement gets log in "/nz/kit/log/pg.log" file, so you need to write a bash which runs with cron or similar tool and extract required information for you.
```